# How do I create a brand new csv file with the time and date in it every time I run my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, file, import-csv

I'm trying to create a new CSV each time I run my code. The title will include some user input and the current date and time.

```
import pygame
import csv
import time 
from datetime import datetime

# Initialize pygame starts 
pygame.init()

# Set the dimensions of the screen
screen_width = 1275
screen_height = 750


# Set the colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

# Set the font
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 20)

# Set the button properties
button_radius = 70
button_x_spacing = 400
button_y_spacing = 200

# Set the button positions
button_positions = [
    (button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing),
    (button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing + 200),
    (button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing + 400)
]

# Initialize the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

# Set the caption
pygame.display.set_caption("Marmoset Buttons")

# Set the clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Set the counters
button0click = 0
button1click = 0
button2click = 0
clickoutsidebutton = 0
trialnum = 0

# Psuedorandom sequence of numbers
sequence = [1,1,2,2,1,2,1,0,1,1, 1,2,1,0,1,0,1,2,1,1, 2,1,0,1,2,1,1,0,1,2, 2,1,0,2,1,1,1,0,1,1,
           1,1,0,1,1,1,2,0,2,1, 2,1,0,1,0,1,1,2,2,1, 1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,2,2, 1,1,2,1,1,2,1,0,1,1,
           1,1,1,0,1,1,2,0,2,1, 0,1,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,0, 1,1,0,1,1,2,1,2,1,0, 2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,0,1,
           1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,2,1,1,1,0,1,1,2, 1,2,1,0,1,2,2,2,1,0, 1,2,1,0,0,1,2,1,2,0,
           1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,2,1, 0,1,2,2,1,1,1,0,1,1, 1,0,1,2,0,1,0,1,1,2, 0,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,0,
           1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0, 1,2,2,1,0,1,1,2,0,1, 1,0,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,0, 1,0,1,1,2,2,1,1,0,0,
           1,2,1,2,1,1,1,0,1,0, 1,1,0,1,2,1,1,2,1,0, 1,2,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0, 1,2,0,2,1,2,1,0,0,1,
           1,1,1,1,0,0,1,2,0,1, 0,1,2,0,1,2,1,2,1,0, 1,0,1,2,1,1,2,0,1,2, 0,0,1,0,2,1,2,1,2,1,
           1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,0, 1,2,1,1,0,2,1,2,1,1, 1,2,2,1,1,2,1,0,0,1, 2,1,2,1,0,2,1,2,0,0,
           1,0,1,1,2,2,1,0,1,0, 0,1,2,1,1,0,1,2,0,1, 1,0,0,1,2,1,2,1,0,0, 1,2,0,0,2,1,0,2,1,1,
           1,1,1,1,2,1,1,0,1,1, 2,1,0,1,1,0,1,2,1,0, 0,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,2,1, 2,1,0,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,
           1,1,0,1,1,1,2,1,1,1, 2,1,2,1,0,0,1,2,1,2, 1,0,1,2,1,2,0,1,2,2, 2,0,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,1,
           1,2,1,0,1,2,0,2,2,2, 1,2,2,1,1,0,1,1,0,0, 1,1,0,1,0,0,1,2,1,2, 1,0,2,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,
           1,2,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1, 1,1,1,2,1,1,0,1,1,1, 1,2,1,0,2,2,1,2,0,1, 1,1,2,2,1,0,1,2,1,0,
           1,2,0,1,1,0,1,1,2,1, 1,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,1,0, 1,2,0,0,0,1,2,2,0,1, 0,2,1,0,0,1,2,2,2,1,
           1,1,2,1,0,1,0,1,2,1, 1,2,1,0,1,1,2,1,0,2, 1,0,2,2,1,0,1,0,2,1, 1,0,2,1,2,1,1,0,0,1,
           1,2,1,2,1,1,1,0,1,1, 1,1,0,0,1,2,1,2,1,0, 1,2,1,2,2,1,0,1,0,0, 2,1,0,2,0,1,0,1,2,1,
           1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1, 1,2,1,0,1,0,1,2,1,0, 2,1,2,2,1,0,1,0,1,1, 2,1,2,0,1,2,1,2,0,0,
           1,1,2,0,2,1,2,1,1,0, 1,2,1,0,0,1,1,2,1,2, 1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,0,0, 1,2,1,0,0,2,1,0,2,1,
           1,0,1,1,2,1,2,0,1,2, 2,1,0,1,1,0,1,2,1,0, 0,1,0,1,2,1,1,2,1,0, 2,2,1,0,0,1,2,1,2,1]

# Truncating list 
trials = int(input("Number of trials: "))
n = len(sequence)
for i in range(0, n - trials):
    sequence.pop()

AnimalName = input("Animal Name: ")
StepName = input("Step: ")
thedatetime = datetime.now()
date = thedatetime.date()
thetime = thedatetime.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
title = AnimalName + "_S" + StepName + "_" + str(date) + "_" + str(thetime)

# Write headers to csv file
with open(title, 'w') as data:
    writer = csv.writer(data)
    writer.writerow(["Trial#", "Event Code", "Time"])

# For loop parsing through sequence 
for i in sequence:

    trialnum += 1

    if trialnum%10 == 0:
        if trialnum == 10:
            data2 = open("Summary", 'w')
            writer2 = csv.writer(data2)
            writer2.writerow(["Trial#", "Button 0 Clicks", "Button 1 Clicks", "Button 2 Clicks", "Outside Clicked", "Time"])
            writer2.writerow([trialnum, button0click, button1click, button2click, clickoutsidebutton, time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))])
        else:
            writer2.writerow([trialnum, button0click, button1click, button2click, clickoutsidebutton, time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))])

    # Delay between buttons 
    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(500)

    # While loop variable 
    button_clicked = False

    # Starts Timer 
    start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    timenow = time.time()
    writer = csv.writer(data)
    writer.writerow([trialnum, i, time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))])

    # Loops while button isn't clickeed 
    while button_clicked == False:

        # Time out for 15 seconds 
        seconds = (pygame.time.get_ticks() - start_time)/1000
        if seconds == 15:
            timenow = time.time()
            writer = csv.writer(data)
            writer.writerow([trialnum, 4, time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))])
            break

        # Checks when screen is touched 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

                # Distance between point touched and button 
                distance_button = pygame.math.Vector2(button_positions[i]) - pygame.math.Vector2(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

                # Checks if distance is within button 
                if distance_button.length() < button_radius:

                    button_clicked = True

                    timenow = time.time()
                    writer = csv.writer(data)
                    writer.writerow([trialnum, 150, time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))])

                    # Counts which buttons were pressed 
                    if i == 0:
                        button0click += 1
                    elif i == 1:
                        button1click += 1
                    elif i == 2:
                        button2click += 1

                # Counts when click was outside of button 
                elif distance_button.length() > button_radius:
                    clickoutsidebutton += 1
                    x = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
                    if x <= 425:
                        timenow = time.time()
                        writer = csv.writer(data)
                        writer.writerow([trialnum, 201, time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))])
                    elif x <= 850:
                        timenow = time.time()
                        writer = csv.writer(data)
                        writer.writerow([trialnum, 200, time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))])
                    elif x > 850:
                        timenow = time.time()
                        writer = csv.writer(data)
                        writer.writerow([trialnum, 202, time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))])   

        # Draws the button 
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, button_positions[i], button_radius)
        text_surface = font.render(f"Button {i}", True, black)
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=button_positions[i])
        screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
        pygame.display.update()

# Printing results 
print("Button 0 was clicked: " + str(button0click) + " times.")
print("Button 1 was clicked: " + str(button1click) + " times.")
print("Button 2 was clicked: " + str(button2click) + " times.")
print("The area around the button was clicked: " + str(clickoutsidebutton) + " times.")
data.close()
data2.close()
```

It's currently giving me the error that no such file or directory exists, however, I'm trying to have it create a new file so it shouldn't be searching for the file to exist already.

Comment: What does `print(title)` show? Does it have any slash characters? That will be treated as a directory separator, and it will fail if the directory doesn't exist.

Comment: Looks like a lot of your example has nothing to do with the question - am I right? Just generate a new file name using datetime.now(). Pass it to open() function or pd.DataFrame.to_csv() etc.

Comment: @Barmar it doesn't show any slashes

Comment: @Pawel this code is for more than just my question. It's just the specific csv part is not working how I intended it to. I Included the whole thing just to be clear on what my code is meant to do.

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Nothing after the part that gets the error is relevant to the question, and probably most the the part before it is irrelevant as well. Including all that other code just makes it hard for us to concentrate on the relevant code.

Comment: I notice you create your file here `with open(title, 'w') as data:`.  Note that `data` closes at the end of the with statement, but you continue trying to use it later in your code. You should be getting an error `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

Comment: I also notice that you are opening a file in your loop `data2 = open("Summary", 'w')`.  Each time you loop the existing file gets overwritten.  If you are intending to write multiple rows to the file it's an error.

Comment: See StackOverflow help [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You are unlikely to get a good answer without following this guideline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to create a new file each time you run your script or module.
Use `datetime` module to obtain current date and time and use some formatting function, like `strftime()` to represent time as string. Use it to generate new file name.

Below is an example with precision up to one second. If you expect your scripts to run concurrently or faster than within period of one second, you might consider adding more precision or something like `uuid`, to avoid name collision.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import csv

... # any initialization code

file_name = f"my_file_{datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')}.csv"
with open (file_name, "w") as csvfile:
   ... # write content of your csv
```

This will produce new file name each time, e.g.:

```
/my_file_20230615_161352.csv
```

Bonus property of such naming convention is that when result files are sorted alphabetically, they will be also sorted chronologically.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv

current_time = datetime.now()

fields = ["Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Second"]
rows = [[current_time.year, current_time.month, current_time.day, 
         current_time.hour, current_time.minute, current_time.second]]

file_name = "DateTime.csv"
with open (file_name, "w") as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile) 
    csvwriter.writerow(fields) 
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: I need the date and time in the title, not in the file itself. Also, The problem I'm having is with the fact it isn't making a new file.